# What are the benefits of using a setTransform for when drawing on a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I am still not certain or even sure of what the setTransform does. I found this code example on the internet and have been messing around with it to see what different changes will do to the setTransform. What are the really uses and benefits from using the setTransform variable as opposed to just drawing a new rectangle.

**Question: What are the benefits and uses of using setTransform?**

Code:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,125,50)

ctx.setTransform(1,0.5,-0.5,1,30,10);
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,250,100);

ctx.setTransform(1,0.5,-0.5,1,30,10);
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,250,100);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each object on the canvas has a current transformation matrix.

The setTransform() method resets the current transform to the identity matrix, and then runs transform() with the same arguments.

In other words, the setTransform() method lets you scale, rotate, move, and skew the current context.

Note: The transformation will only affect drawings made after the setTransform method is called.

[Source.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_settransform.asp)

- Some interesting [examples](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/february/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-transform-function.html) of its usage.
- Another good [explanation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/69388)